# How to make a monster hit a random player in javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to make a game in vue js where i have tank, dps and healer

```
data: {
        tankHealth: 100,
        healerHealth: 100,
        dpsHealth: 100,
        monsterHealth: 200,
        gameRunning: false,
        turns: [],
},
```

I have a button that when it gets clicked it enters a setinterval function where every 1 second the tank and dps attack the monster. and the healer heals one of the players. But when it comes to monster attacking the player, i want the monster to attack randomly one of the players like that:

```
var monsterDamage = self.calculateDamage(10,20); // returns a random number between 10 and 20
var number = self.randomNumberFn(1,3);
// get a random number here so i can randomly pick a player to attack
switch(number) {
    case 1:
        self.dpsHealth -= monsterDamage;
        if(self.dpsHealth <= 0) {
            self.dpsHealth = 0;
            break;
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        self.tankHealth -= monsterDamage;
        if(self.tankHealth <= 0) {
            self.tankHealth = 0;
            break;
        }
        break;
    case 3:
        self.healerHealth -= monsterDamage;
        if(self.healerHealth <= 0) {
            self.healerHealth = 0;
            break;
        }
        break;
}
```

The problem comes when one of the players is dead. In that case, I want the monster to attack only the players that are alive. In the model i have right now, even if one of the players is dead the monster keeps attacking him

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this?

```js
do {
var n1 = 1;
var n2 = 3;

var monsterDamage = self.calculateDamage(10, 20);
var number = self.randomNumberFn(n1, n2);

switch (number) {
    case 1:
        if (self.dpsHealth === 0) { // === checks type too...
            n1 = 2;
            continue;
        }
        self.dpsHealth = doDamage(self.dpsHealth, monsterDamage);
        break;
    case 2:
        if (self.dpsHealth === 0) {
            continue;
        }
        self.tankHealth = doDamage(self.tankHealth, monsterDamage);
        break;
    case 3:
        if (self.dpsHealth === 0) {
            n2 = 2;
            continue;
        }
        self.healerHealth = doDamage(self.healerHealth, monsterDamage);
        break;
}
} while((self.dpsHealth + self.tankHealth + self.healerHealth) === 0)

function doDamage(health, damage) {
    if ((health - damage) <= 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return health - damage;
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought about that solution, but in this case if the dpsHealth for example evaluates to 0, it exits the switch, and no player gets attacked in this iteration. I want to make it in such a way that every iteration a player gets hit. So, for example, if one of the players health is 0, it targets one of the other 2

Comment: "it exits the switch means what?"

Comment: like when you wrote "if(self.dpsHealth === 0) continue" in that case it wil not decrease any of the players health

Comment: If the health is 0 it isn't right? Should it be negative?

Comment: No, i mean if the health evaluates to 0, it will enter the 'continue' statement. When it enters it, it will leave the switch statement and continue with the rest of the code. But the problem is that no player will get hit in this iteration. I am trying to make it look like this: "if dps health is 0, hit one of the other 2 players, "

Answer (score -1):

To solve this problem, you can create an array to hold your living humans, and iterate through said array for a random value.

```
let livingHumans = []; 

if(dpsHealth > 0) {
  livingHumans.push({name:'dpsHealth', health:dpsHealth});
}
if(tankHealth > 0) {
  livingHumans.push({name:'tankHealth', health:tankHealth});
}
if(healerHealth > 0) {
  livingHumans.push({name:'healerHealth', health:healerHealth});
}

// get random value from array
let number = self.randomNumber(1, livingHumans.length)
// once you receive the output, 
// you can use the name property to find the player in your object. 

name = livingHumans[number].name;
console.log(data[name]);
```

Comment: Thought about that, but when i push them, they get passed by value and if i change the value in the array, it doesn't affect the real variable. And if i try to assign the changed value from the array to the original one, i have no way of knowing which one to change in advance, because every time a diffrent player may die and if i have 2 values in the array  i couldn't know which 2 players belong to these values

Comment: Thank you very much dude, just tried it after your edit, and it works perfect, it was easy but the solution just didn't come to my mind. I don't know why they gave you 'not usefult' when it works like charm. Thank you very much again.